# Determine client's timezone using nginx

Tags: nginx, timezone, timezone-offset

Is there any way to determine client's timezone using nginx. Is there any nginx module that can tell timezone by looking IP address and then country/city like ngx_http_geoip_module.

Basically, I don't want to extract it using js and pass it in some GET parameter, session or cookie or perhaps store in user profile in the database. Well, these are my last resorts.

**Environment**: Django-python <-> nginx. (Already tried 'django-easy-timezones' and it works)

Regards